# I want to draw movable bitmap and later erase its part using canvas in android studio

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a sticker bitmap and draw the sticker on canvas and erasing by moving finger on it
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrS0Y.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dy4m.jpg)